# Vue js split bundle into few files via Webpack

Tags: web, webpack, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

Can i split vue generation files via wabpack on few files. I need use login page without other component. If i have structure smth like this:

- components

  - Login.vue
  - Home.vue
  - etc.

In the build dir i want have

- js

  - bundle
  - login_bundle
- css

  - main.css
  - login.css
- index.html
- login.html

Have webpack some ability for this?

Comment: Yes it does have the ability to do that.  See here https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/

Comment: I think you  want to pre-render some of your routes. See https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try eager importing.

```
const dependency = () => import(
  /* webpackChunkName: "login-chunk" */
  /* webpackMode: "eager" */
  'module in Login.vue'
).then(m => m.default || m);
```

Comment: thank you. I find other solution/ I split login page and vue app. Login page i use for Spring securuty

Comment: @Lukashenko Yevhenii So you setup another app for the login?

Comment: I add page into backend templates and return it on login request, and after that i return build vue app for user